# the method actionPerformed is not working

Tags: jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

This is my current code and the showButton is now working, thanks to you, but unfortunately the totalButton is still not. Could you me help figure this out?

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class GUISS extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
new GUISS();
}
private JButton totalButton, showButton;
private JTextField productField,  productField2, productField3, productField4, productField5;
private JTextField priceField, priceField2, priceField3, priceField4, priceField5;
private JTextField quantityField, quantityField2, quantityField3, quantityField4, quantityField5;
private JTextField totalField, totalField2, totalField3, totalField4, totalField5, emptyField, totalAmountField;
static double num1 , num2, num3, num4, num5, ans, ans2;
static double CBOX1 = 25.00, CBOX2 = 25.00, CBOX3 = 39.00, CBOX4 = 25.00;

public GUISS()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Mcdonalds");
    setSize(520,200);

    productField = new JTextField("Best Sellers", 10);
    productField. setEditable(false);

    productField2 = new JTextField("Burger Mcdo", 10);
    productField2.setEditable(false);

    productField3 = new JTextField("Hot Fudge Sundae", 10);
    productField3.setEditable(false);

    productField4 = new JTextField("CheeseBurger", 10);
    productField4.setEditable(false);

    productField5 = new JTextField("Regular McFries", 10);
    productField5.setEditable(false);

    priceField = new JTextField("Alacarte Price", 10);
    priceField.setEditable(false);

    priceField2 = new JTextField("P25.00", 10);
    priceField2.setEditable(false);

    priceField3 = new JTextField("P25.00", 10);
    priceField3.setEditable(false);

    priceField4 = new JTextField("P39.00", 10);
    priceField4.setEditable(false);

    priceField5 = new JTextField("P25.00", 10);
    priceField5.setEditable(false);





    quantityField = new JTextField("Quantity", 10);
    quantityField.setEditable(false);

    quantityField2 = new JTextField(10);

    quantityField3 = new JTextField(10);

    quantityField4 = new JTextField(10);

    quantityField5 = new JTextField(10);


    totalField = new JTextField("Total Price", 10);
    totalField.setEditable(false);

    totalField2 = new JTextField("P0.0", 10);
    totalField2.setEditable(false);

    totalField3 = new JTextField("P0.0", 10); 
    totalField3.setEditable(false);

    totalField4 = new JTextField("P0.0", 10);
    totalField4.setEditable(false);

    totalField5 = new JTextField("P0.0", 10);
    totalField5.setEditable(false);

    emptyField = new JTextField(10);
   // JButton showButton = new JButton("Show price");
    //JTextFieldtotalButton = new JButton("Total Amount");
    totalAmountField = new JTextField("P0.0", 10);
    totalAmountField.setEditable(false);
  JTextField CashField = new JTextField(10);


 totalButton = new JButton("Total Amount");
  showButton = new JButton("Show price");

    add(productField);
    add(priceField);
    add(quantityField);
    add(totalField);

    add(productField2);
    add(priceField2);
    add(quantityField2);
    add(totalField2);

    add(productField3);
    add(priceField3);
    add(quantityField3);
    add(totalField3);

    add(productField4);
    add(priceField4);
    add(quantityField4);
    add(totalField4);

    add(productField5);
    add(priceField5);
    add(quantityField5);
    add(totalField5);

    add(showButton);
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(totalButton);
    totalButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(totalAmountField);
    setVisible(true);




    }

    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
    {  

     System.out.println("Entered action performed");

    if(e.getSource() == showButton ){
        if(!quantityField2.getText().equals(emptyField.getText())){
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quantityField2.getText()));
            ans = num1 * CBOX1 ;
            totalField2.setText(String.valueOf("P" + ans));
        }
        if(!quantityField3.getText().equals(emptyField.getText())){
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quantityField3.getText()));
            ans = num1 * CBOX2 ;
            totalField3.setText(String.valueOf("P" + ans));
        }
        if(!quantityField4.getText().equals(emptyField.getText())){
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quantityField4.getText()));
            ans = num1 * CBOX3 ;
            totalField4.setText(String.valueOf("P" + ans));
        }
        if(!quantityField5.getText().equals(emptyField.getText())){
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quantityField5.getText()));
            ans = num1 * CBOX4 ;
            totalField5.setText(String.valueOf("P" + ans));
       }           
        else if(e.getSource() == totalButton){
        if(!totalField2.getText().equals(0)){
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(totalField2.getText()));
        }
        if(!totalField3.getText().equals(0)){
            num3 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(totalField3.getText()));
        }
        if(!totalField4.getText().equals(0)){
            num4 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(totalField4.getText()));
        }
        if(!totalField5.getText().equals(0)){
            num5 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(totalField5.getText()));
        }
        else {
        ans2 = num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 ;

        totalAmountField.setText(String.valueOf("P" + ans2));
    }
}
    }
}
}
```

thanks for helping, this code is very important for me

Comment: you have not set action to any component..

Comment: I already set an action in the actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the problem here is that you did not add an action listener to the button to listen to the events that are triggered by the button called showButton. You need to add the following to your code after adding the button.

```
public GUISS()
{
    ...//your code as is
    add(showButton);
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
    ...//the rest of your code as is
}
```

Also to make sure that you are entering the actionPerformed method try to print something at the start of the method and see that it is output to the console. The line of code I added is adding the actionListener to the current instance of GUISS. That means that the instance you create of GUISS will listen to the actions performed by the button showButton. For more information you can look at the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Another problem here is that you are creating a local variable called showButton as well and that's the button the action is being added to not the instance variable showButton, to solve this problem modify your code as below:

```
public GUISS() {
    //JButton showButton = new JButton("Show price"); 
}
```

basically comment out the local variable called showButton. With this line not being commented the if condition for the getSource will not give the instance variable so they will not be equal.

Finally you have a bug with the condition regarding the totalButton, the totalButton condition if e.getSource() == totalButton is placed inside the condition of e.getSource() == showButton and as such it will never get executed you should re factor the else if to be the else if of the if e.getSource() == showButton

Comment: I already put showButton.addActionListener(this); as well as totalButton.addActionListener(this); but it's still not working even though there is no syntax error.

Comment: Did you add the a print statement in the beginning of the actionPerformed method to make sure if it enters it or not?

Comment: pls tell me what am i going to add.

Comment: try to add `public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
    {  System.out.println('Entered action performed');
       //rest of the code as is }` Run the main method again, if you see the console outputing 'Entered action performed' then the problem is in the conditions that you are using in the method if not then it is something else this should help you figure out where the problem is'

Comment: I have your code running and I modified the solution to make it work, please read the solution and try it out. Tell me if there is a problem here or accept the solution and up vote the solution if it works for you, thanks

Comment: I already put  {  System.out.println('Entered action performed'); } and there's error 'error:unclosed character literal'

Comment: Use `System.out.println("Entered action performed");` and also comment out the declaration of showButton local variable as I mentioned in the modified answer

Comment: the console is outputing 'Enter action Performed' so the problem is in the condition. so how's that?

Comment: Quoting the modified solution(please read it once more it has been modified) "Another problem here is that you are creating a local variable called showButton as well and that's the button the action is being added to not the instance variable showButton, to solve this problem modify your code as below:

`public GUISS() {
    //JButton showButton = new JButton("Show price"); 
}`

basically comment out the local variable called showButton. With this line not being commented the if condition for the getSource will not give the instance variable so they will not be equal."

Comment: Please remember to accept the question and up vote the solution if it solved the problem or continue asking here if it didn't work yet :)

Comment: Yes I already comment out the local variable showButton and the error is 'NullPointerException:null(in java.awt.Container)' pertaining to 'add(showButton)'

Comment: I cannot identify what's the error in the if condition. pls tell me what am i going to change. thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and put the latest code you have, most likely you commented out the initialization of the showButton instance variable and the local variable showButton. Please note that there are two variables called showButton in the previous code

Comment: I already edit my code. Sorry I cannot vote up the sol'n because I'm a newbie and i need more reputation.

Comment: Modified the answer to point you in the right direction of solving the problem

Comment: The only problem here is the  totalButton = new JButton("Total Amount");, it's still not working. with this code, could you help me figure this out?

Comment: What you want to do is to say if the showButton is clicked do the following else if it is totalButton that's clicked do something else. You have the else if statement with regards to totalButton inside the condition for the showButton so you need to move it you can figure this one on your own easily

Comment: what I want to do is that after i clicked the 'showButton', which shows the equivalent price of each products, i will click the 'totalButton' so the total amount of all products will set at the 'totalAmountField'